# Can I make an Xbox 360 controller emulate a PS3 controller on PC?

Tags: pc, controllers, dynasty-warriors-7

I have an Xbox 360 gamepad, which I want to use as a PS3 gamepad. I want to make it compatible with the game Shin Sangoku Musou 6 Moushouden (Dynasty Warriors 7) on PC. Is there any emulator software can do this?

To clarify, I am trying to find a PS3 Controller emulator. I know there is an [Xbox 360 Controller emulator](http://code.google.com/p/x360ce/), I am trying to find a similar one but for PS3 controller.

I am doing this because Shin Sangoku Musou 6 Moushouden (Dynasty Warriors 7) on PC supports the PS3 controller best. When I use my Xbox 360 gamepad it doesn't recognize the buttons correctly and fully, and vibration also doesn't work.

Comment: How is emulating a PS3 controller going to help you play a PC game?

Comment: This doesn't make sense; the PS3 controller doesn't have official drivers for the PC so making the 360 controller act like it wouldn't be useful. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to find a PS3 controller emulator. There is a XBOX 360 Controller emulator : http://code.google.com/p/x360ce/. I am trying to find a similar one but for PS3 controller.

Comment: Why I am doing this ? Because Shin Sangoku Musou 6 Moushouden on PC supports best for PS3 controller. When I use my XBOX 360 gamepad it doesn't recognize the buttons correctly and fully, and vibration also doesn't work.

Comment: @JatSing Copy and Pasting the information you posted in your question doesn't help us when we read that information already in your posted question...

Comment: Hi @Foxtrot, I pasted it in comment because it is the updated information, it wasn't here before.

Answer (score 1):

It may be easier to invest a couple of dollars and buy a second hand PS3 controller from Gamestop or similar store.

It wouldn't be that expensive and you can have a controller for any other titles you will get.

Answer (score 0):

I believe MotionInJoy allows you to emulate a X360 controller using a PS3 controller if that is what you are looking for.

If not, MotionInJoy is basically the unofficial driver for PS3 controllers on Windows.

Comment: I think he is looking for the opposite.

Comment: Yes, I am looking for the opposite

Comment: There's none that exist right now, but if you use X360ce and remap buttons until they are properly mapped, it's a workaround.

Comment: @SakuyaFM, how, since X360ce is an emulator of Xbox360 gamepad not PS3 ?

Answer (score 0):

http://dl.qj.net/playstation-3/tools-and-utilities/sixaxis-driver-for-pc.html This is a driver which will make your ps3 controller recognized on PC if that is what you are looking for, if not than sorry..

Comment: He's looking for a X360 driver/utility that will allow him to use an X360 controller and emulate it as a PS3 controller. AFAIK, there are none that exist.

Answer (score 0):

To me it seems you actually have to get a ps3 controller. Sorry. I cannot find an emulator. I think it might be because of the possible button differences (triangle,square,circle,x, rather than a,b,x,y). I know this isn't what your looking for, and I really am sorry... I spent quite a while trying to find a sufficient answer but couldn't find a single thing, except for one youtube video that I cannot seem to find again, and wasn't super helpful anyway (I believe it was just using a ps3 controller with an emulator, but titled incorrectly).

Answer (score 0):

I believe that what you are looking for is a different driver needed for your XBox controller. Visit this [page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee417014%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for the official direct-input drivers.

Do note that:

```
-The left and right trigger buttons will act as a single button, not independently
-The vibration effects will not be available
-Querying for headset devices will not be available
```